# Report/Export first child of Master-Detail relationship

Tags: data-migration

I have a pair of objects in a Master-Detail relationship, and we've realized that for business purposes, we need to treat the "first child" and the "last child" differently from the rest.

We'll actually code these items differently by choosing a different picklist option, and our app's interface will make this easy going going.

However, we have 10,000s of records already, and I'm not sure how best to identify and update the existing data.  What is a good way to do this?

(I have an idea, which I'm going to post as a first answer -- but it feels brittle and I wonder if there are better ways to do this. And there's always Excel...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need to get a list of records (or record IDs) for all the existing "first child" records, so that you can do a mass update with a tool like Workbench, Demandtools, or the Data Loader. Here's one way to do that:

1. Add a custom DateTime roll-up field called `Parent.Date_of_First_Child__c`, and summarize the records using the `LOWER` function to get the earliest date.
2. Add a formaula field called `Child.Is_First_Child__c`, which checks whether its date matches the date on the parent object.
3. You can know safely report on or export these records knowing that they're the first!
4. If any of your data have identical date stamps, though, this won't necessarily work...

(And you can do something similar to identify 'last children')